# Parse.com and Paypal integration

Tags: javascript, ios, paypal, parse-platform

I use Parse.com for backend for my application. Because of the limited function on Paypal iOS sdk, I tried to use Paypal with Parse cloud code http request but it cannot even get the token from Paypal. I searched google and realized that a lot of people have a same problem like me. Is there anyone implemented paypal REST API with parse cloud code?

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak about paypal specifically, but when I use stripe(another developer payment system), I do not create the tokens through my backend. The tokens are created directly between the device, and stripe. Everything I do with the token after that is done through my backend(Parse) though.

Comment: Thanks. I originally used stripe, and implemented every details. But because of legal issue, I could not use stripe(It is kind of complex). But thanks for your quick answer.